# Double as close to 0 as possible?

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I need a value as close to 0 as possible. I need to be able to divide through this value, but it should be effectively 0.

Does Java provide an easy way of generating a double with only the least significant bit set? Or do I have to calculate it myself?

---

//EDIT: A little background information, because someone requested it. I know that my soultion is not a particularly clean one, but here you are:

I am writing a program for homework. It calculates the resistance of a circuit consisting of multiple resistors in parallel and serial circuits.

It is a 2nd year programming class. Our teacher still designs classes for us, we need to implement them according to his design.

Parallel circuits involve calculation of `1/*resistance*`, therefore my program prohibits creation of resistors with 0 Ohm. Physics tells you that this is impossible anyway (you have just a tiny little resistance in every metal).

However, the example circuit we should use to test the program contains a 0 Ohm resistor. It is placed in a serial circuit, but resistors do not know where they are (the teacher designed it that way), so I cannot change my program to allow resistors with 0 Ohm resistance in serial circuits only.

Two solutions:

1. Allow 0 Ohm resistors in any case - if division by 0 occurs, well, bad luck
2. Set the resistor not to 0, but to a resistance one can neglect.

Both are not very good. The first one seemed not too good to me, and neither did the second, but I had to decide.

It was just a random choice that threw up the problem. I could not let go without solving it, so switching to the first one was not an option anymore ;-)

Comment: When you say “I need to be able to divide through this value”, do you mean without producing a NaN, or without producing an overflow? Because dividing almost any finite value by the smallest positive nonzero double will produce overflow.

Comment: Without producing a NaN. I couldn´t care less about overflows in my case.

Comment: It would be interesting to hear more on why you need this. It sounds a bit hacky.

Comment: The closest value to zero possible is zero. I could write a proof if needed.

Comment: What is it you really want to accomplish with this value? Turn positive values into +infinity, zero into zero, and negative values into -infinity? Or something else? Division is an expensive operation; it may be cheaper to simply copy the sign bit from an input to an infinity (although I do not know whether Java implementations optimize this well).

Comment: I updated my question with some background detail. Don´t grudge me for being insane ;-)

Comment: If the number being divided is `1`, as it is according to your extra information, then you can safely use `+0.0` as divisor. The result will not be `NaN` but `+inf`, which will work as you would expect from a positive infinity in the rest of the computations (in particular `1.0 / (1.0 / +0.0) == +0.0`. Division by zero is not forbidden in IEEE 754 arithmetic. It is not necessary to substitute a value that is almost zero.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`Double.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE):

> A constant holding the *smallest positive **nonzero** value* of type `double`, 2<sup>-1074</sup>. It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal `0x0.0000000000001P-1022` and also equal to `Double.longBitsToDouble(0x1L)`.

Comment: I always thought that MIN_VALUE was negative. But if you (and the documentation) say so...

Comment: @fNek I too thought that, before I first time looked into the doc. :)

Comment: For any .NET developers arriving here: Use [Double.Epsilon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.double.epsilon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `Double.MinValue` is a very large negative number.

Comment: Surely if you _are_ dividing by `Double.MIN_VALUE`, then you're pretty much guaranteed an overflow?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to divide by "zero" you can actually just use `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` as the result.

Comment: This is not what I mean. The value must be zero for some other reason, but I happen to have to divide by it.

Comment: surely Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY?

Comment: Only for numerators larger than 0.[fifteenzeros]1 though.